# How to bind a character device in /dev directory as the keyboard?

Tags: virtualization

I have written a character device, and I want to declare it as the keyboard and use it to generate events from the virtual keyboard. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've written the character device driver yourself, and it is intended to be used as an input device, then you might be best off altering your driver to work as an input device instead of a generic character device.

Fortunately, there is some good documentation in the kernel tree, at:

```
Documentation/input/input-programming.txt
```

For an online version, take a look at the [input-programming.txt](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/input/input-programming.txt) file in the linux tree on kernel.org.

Basically, you'll create a `struct input_dev`, and register it with the input subsystem with `input_register_device`. Input events can then be sent to the input layer with `input_event`, or one of the helper functions like `input_report_key`.